# Change Json structure javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How do I change the format of the below json format to expected output:

```
[
  {
    "type": "System Usability Score",
    "score": 74,
    "date": "2020-03-19T18:30:00.000+0000"
  },
  {
    "type": "System Usability Score",
    "score": 87,
    "date": "2020-03-31T18:30:00.000+0000"
  }
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  {
    "name": "System Usability Score",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "2020-03-19T18:30:00.000+0000",
        "value": 74
      },
      {
        "name": "2020-03-31T18:30:00.000+0000",
        "value": 87
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you mean: I get data from a JSON API and want to transform the structure of the resulting JavaScript object?

Comment: @yunzen yes. Exactly

Comment: Then you should edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
"use strict";

const input = [
  {
    "type": "System Usability Score",
    "score": 74,
    "date": "2020-03-19T18:30:00.000+0000"
  },
  {
    "type": "Net Promoter Score",
    "score": 89,
    "date": "2020-03-23T18:30:00.000+0000"
  },
  {
    "type": "Net Promoter Score",
    "score": 78,
    "date": "2020-03-25T18:30:00.000+0000"
  },
  {
    "type": "System Usability Score",
    "score": 87,
    "date": "2020-03-31T18:30:00.000+0000"
  }
]


var output = input.reduce((collect, {type, score, date}) => {
  let el, series
  if (el = collect.find(({name}) => name === type)) {
    series = el.series
  } else  {
    series = collect[collect.push({name: type, series: []}) - 1].series
  }
  series.push({name: date, value: score})
  return collect
}, [])

console.log(output)
```